# Visiting Any URI other than Root Resulting in 404 - nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a URL in the form of `www.example.com`, and am using nginx as the web server. When I go to `www.example.com`, the site works fine, however whenever I go to `www.example.com/anyUri`, I receive a 404. Here is the location element in my sites-available file:

```
location ~*/(.*) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ = $404 ;
}
```

The website is built in React, so there is no real directory, but rather different routes. When I click on a link to navigate to a different route, it loads correctly, but if I try to access that same route directly through the URL, I receive the 404 as well. For example, if from my home page I click "Contact", the URL changes to `www.example.com/contact` and loads the "Contact" component as desired. If I refresh the page or type in `www.example.com/contact` manually, I receive the 404. I have my website set up to handle the nonexistent URIs accordingly, and do not need nginx to handle those. Instead, I want nginx to go to `www.example.com/anyUri` and let the website logic take over from there. I have tried looking up the different patterns online, however none seem to be working as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `nginx.conf` file is what I have been using - works like a charm for me.

```sh
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /your/web/root/path/nginx/html;

  index index.html;

  location / {
    # Adds support for HTML5 history mode
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    # -or-
    # try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: Turns out, the issue came from this line `try_files $uri $uri/ = $404`. Changing it to what you had `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html` did the trick! I know that's not what you suggested, but looks like your solution worked lol

Comment: @Sal if the subdomains are pointing to NGINX I believe it *should* work.